# Countifs with nested OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a countifs function:

```
COUNTIFS(DB!$C:$C,"<>"&"",DB!$Q:$Q,OR(DB!$Q:$Q="-",DB!$Q:$Q>Summary!B7),DB!$N:$N,"<="&B7)
```

The problem must be the nested OR statement.

It's a new condition, I was using something else previously that was not accurate.

I need to select data where:
DB!C:C is not blank;
DB!Q:Q equals "-" OR is greater than B7;
DB!N:N is less than or equal to B7.

What is the proper way to nest this OR statement within the countifs statement?

Comment: OR cannot be used with countifs...all criteria is always anded, you need to use SUMPRODUCT and use addition to replace OR and multiplication to replace AND something like this to do a OR: =SUMPRODUCT(1*(((H15:H17>2)+(I15:I17>2))>1))

Comment: Ach, shame countifs would have prevented me having to update range on each update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `OR()` within `COUNTIFS` (or `SUMIFS` and similar `...IF` functions).

You can add the `COUNTIFS` for the most straightforward workaround:

```
=COUNTIFS(DB!$C:$C,"<>"&"",DB!$Q:$Q,"-",DB!$N:$N,"<="&B7)+
 COUNTIFS(DB!$C:$C,"<>"&"",DB!$Q:$Q,">"&Summary!B7,DB!$N:$N,"<="&B7)
```

But you can also use `SUMPRODUCT` in the following way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DB!$C:$C<>"")*(((DB!$Q:$Q="-")+(DB!$Q:$Q>Summary!B7))>0)*(DB!$N:$N<=B7))
```

It's better if you define the range better though in this case, since `SUMPRODUCT` will be really slow on large ranges and if the range goes all the way to the bottom of the file.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is data that meets both countifs statements as then they would be double counted.  If there may be duplicates you could subtract a third countif with all the criteria from the first two functions in it.

Comment: @gtwebb True, but in this particular case, the first `COUNTIFS` gets results based on a text `-` and the other from a value, so there's no possible overlap. If there's any overlap, the SUMPRODUCT too will have to be edited.

Comment: This overlap can be avoided with the method @CRondao suggested: `=SUMPRODUCT((DB!$C:$C<>"")*(((DB!$Q:$Q="-")+(DB!$Q:$Q>Summary!B7))>=1)*(DB!$N:$N<=B7))`

Comment: @Snoozer I have this formula in the answer as well :)

Comment: I think your formula lacks a key bit of the OR statement, the `>=1`. In my testing it didn't work without this